# Using mysql query to get the user3 not following user1

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js

I have a called users

| id | name | username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | user1 |
| 2 | Mary | user2 |
| 3 | Bucket | user3 |

second table relationship

| id | followerid | followId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

I want to use sql query to get the user3 not following user1

```
export const getUsers = (req, res) => {
   const q ="SELECT  r.*, u.id AS userId, name, profilePic FROM relationships AS r RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON r.followerUserId = u.id";

   db.query(q, (err, data) => {
       if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
            return res.json(data);
   });
};
```

but I am getting all the users

Comment: Define better what does "*it's not working*" mean. Are you getting any errors? Were you expecting different outputs? If that's the case, can you share your current output and the expected one?

Comment: Also the title of your post says "*get the user3 not following user1*", but in your query there's no reference to either user3 or user1. Is something missing to your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice: Don't ever use right outer joins. If you want outer joins, use left outer joins.

You have:

```
SELECT  r.*, u.id AS userId, name, profilePic
FROM relationships AS r
RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON r.followerUserId = u.id
```

Which equals:

```
SELECT  r.*, u.id AS userId, name, profilePic
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN relationships AS r ON r.followerUserId = u.id
```

So you say: show me all users, no matter if they have a relationship entry or not. If they follow others, show all those relationships.

This is not at all the task you describe. You want only those users that don't follow user #1, or so I understand this. And you don't want user #1 themselves either, it seems.

(It's a bit weird, that there is no reference to user #1 in your query. Did you think the DBMS would guess that this was supposed to be about user #1?)

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT followerid FROM relationships WHERE followId = 1)
and id <> 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not referring users, while you specifically need user3, or to extend, "people" not following user1, you can craft a query about it.

We can use `NOT EXISTS` to gather users that satisfy either one of these two conditions:

- the user is user1 (we want people that don't follow user1, I guess we don't want user1 himself)
- the user is a follower, and the user follows user1

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM relationships r 
                  WHERE (u.id = r.followerId AND r.followId = 1) 
                     OR u.id = 1)
```

Once the query is [tested](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uUJ69MenY9LUaDATitNBEg/1), you can move it inside your code, which would become as follows:

```
export const getUsers = (req, res) => {
   const q ="SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relationships r WHERE (u.id = r.followerId AND r.followId = 1) OR u.id = 1)";

   db.query(q, (err, data) => {
       if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
            return res.json(data);
   });
};
```

Even though I'm noticing you're additionally selecting other fields that are not available in the sample table you've shown, this should give you a solid baseline to expand on.